# Zend - routing rules based on parameters number

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, router, zend-controller-router

in my project I'm using zend to handle routing. Atm we've got routing rules which looks like this:
array(
          'match' => 'page',
          'params' => array('page', 'idConfiguration'),
          'controller' => 'controler1',
          'action' => 'action1'
      )

So we access this action by: http://base_url/page/1/1223324 for example.

Is there a simple solution to create rules so i can determine which action is called based on number of params?

I'd like it to look the following way:
http://base_url/ - action 0
http://base_url/pageNumber - action 1 
http://base_url/pageNumber/idConfiguration - action 2
http://base_url/pageNumber/idConfiguration/someotherparam - action 3

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ini-based solution (hope I understand what you want):

```
routes.action0.route = "/:pageNumber"
routes.action0.defaults.controller = "controller0"
routes.action0.defaults.action = "action0"
routes.action0.reqs.pageNumber = "\d+"

routes.action1.route = "/:pageNumber/:idConfiguration"
routes.action1.defaults.controller = "controller1"
routes.action1.defaults.action = "action1"
routes.action1.reqs.pageNumber = "\d+"
routes.action1.reqs.idConfiguration= "\d+"

routes.action2.route = "/:pageNumber/:idConfiguration/:someOtherParam"
routes.action2.defaults.controller = "controller2"
routes.action2.defaults.action = "action2"
routes.action2.reqs.pageNumber = "\d+"
routes.action2.reqs.idConfiguration= "\d+"
routes.action2.reqs.someOtherParam = "someOtherRegEx"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass [Zend_Controller_Router_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard) and create the routing behaviour you like. Of the top of my head, and without testing it you can try something like this:

```
class MyRoute extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route
{
    public function match($path) 
    {
        $result = array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => substr_count($path, '/'),
        );

        return $result;
    } 
}
```

You would need to add validations, of course. Also you should return `FALSE` if the URL doesn't match and you want it to be tested with other routes. But this should give you a general idea on how to work this out.